# Fading out combined with movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

I hope this question is no exact duplicate ... But none of those related questions helped me to tackle my problem. I want to animate an endless "stream" of rectangles. Whenever the user clicks an element I want:

- All elements, including the new one, slowly moving to the left until the second rectangle is in the place of the first rectangle
- The first rectangle to fade out
- A new rectangle to fade in at the end

So far I have come up with this [(According jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/DasGurke/BsEWp/6/):

```
    $('.block').first().animate({
        opacity: 0.75,
        left: '-=50'
    }, 300, function() {
        $('.block').first().remove();
        addBlock(index++);
    });
```

Animating the opacity works fine, moving to the left does not. I would suspect this is probably due too the surrounding div. But to be honest I have not much clue about web techniques, thats why I am asking you.

- What can I do to make my rectangles move left?
- Can I possibly move them to the left while "sliding under" the surrounding div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `position:relative` to your css `.block` entry, use `marginLeft` and you'll get the desired effect -

http://jsfiddle.net/BsEWp/67/

To slide it under a wrapper div, all you'll have to do is give the wrapper element a css property `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Wow, thats a quick answer. But somehow this only causes the first element to be moved to the left. I was hoping the other elements would dynamically take up the "remaining" space. Is there a possibility to let those other rectangles "follow up" without animating them explictly?

Comment: It seems that
$('.block').first().animate({
            opacity: 0.75,
            margin-left: '-=50'
        }
will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

May be like this?

```
$('.block').first().animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    width: '-=50'
}
```

or:

```
$('.block').first().animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    marginLeft: '-=50'
}
```

it's works